# Strapi: How to disable registration?

Tags: strapi

I'm new to the headless CMS Strapi and wondering how I can disable the registration of new users at the admin panel. I don't want to remove the admin panel completely, just the registration because all admin users are already registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it. It's in the admin panel under `Roles & Permissions > Advanced Settings > Enable sign-ups`

Comment: In v3.3.0 it's under `Settings` > `Users & permissions plugin` > `Advanced Settings` > `Enable sign-ups`